# Predictive Intelligence Implementation - Content Web Recommendation

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations

I'm trying to implement Web Recommendations in my website but it's not working as expected.

We've followed the instructions to implement the content catalog, the codes and create the recommendations. No recommendation is shown in the website, but the report shows number of visitors who where influenced by our recommentations.

I don't see any errors when I check the Personalization Builder Status Console. The recommendation preview also runs normally with no error.

What could I have missed?

Comment: There can be a number of issues. Especially around the configuration of scenarios. Have you tried to implement the basic recommendation code with default scenarios? And are you just using the standard code? Or are you using the JSON based recommendation feed?